# Getting tower location instead of gps

Tags: gps, embedded, microcontroller, at-command

I have a GSM/GPS unit connected to a Microcontroller, the communication between them works fine. I am able to get the GPS and send it to the Microcontroller but there are times when the unit is inside the building so I can't really get the current GPS location, instead I want to get the tower location.

The AT command I'm using to get the LAC and CI with response is as follows.

**Command: AT+CREG=2**

**Response:** 
[image]

From this, LAC = `2BCB or 11211` and CI = `2B9A or 11162`

The sim card I'm using is registered under T-Mobile, so the MCC = `310` and MNC = `260` by looking them up [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code). However when I plug those values on this [website](http://www.cell2gps.com), I don't get the location.

**What am I missing ?**

I noticed when I try to check the current network with **AT+COPS?** I don't get the same results as shown [here](http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/network-information-automaticmanual-selection/).

[image]

Am I suppose to manually set the network information ? If yes please someone provide me with the correct format. I tried sending **At+COPS=4,2,”310 260″** but that threw me an error.

Here is the [AT command document](http://www.docdroid.net/lnf8/at-document-full-v2127.pdf.html) I am following, it has a different format. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I'm former governor Jessie the Body Ventura.  You're probably connecting to an Interceptor tower.  That's the NSA spying on you.

Comment: Lol, I am starting to think that I need to set up the network information manually since I am not getting a good response with the `AT+COPS?` command.

Comment: Any feedback on this issue?

Comment: Got no idea.  But it *could* be an interceptor.  I have no idea how this stuff works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I just had to plug in the values in this [website](http://cellphonetrackers.org/gsm/gsm-tracker.php) instead of the original [website](http://www.cell2gps.com/) I was using.